# Would you implement an interface for 1 class or 2 interface for 2 classes

Tags: c#, class, interface

When you see this interface would you split it up in 2 interfaces and 2 concrete classes?
Or would you create 1 interface and 1 class.

Just consider for me it seems an overhead to create another interface and classes just for 2 methods but well...

Another other idea how to cope with such a case?

```
public interface IUnitDataProvider
{
        // Testplan methods
        IEnumerable<Unit> GetTestplanRootUnits(int templateId, int testplanId);        

        // Template methods
        IEnumerable<Unit> GetTemplateRootUnits(int templateId);
        void AddUnit(Unit unit);
        void DeleteUnit(int unitId);
        bool UnitExists(string unitName, int templateId);

        // Mutual methods
        IEnumerable<Unit> GetChildrenUnits(int templateId, int parentId);
}
```

Comment: Treating another interface as an overhead is something new

Comment: You should create as many interfaces as your application design requires - as simple as this.

Comment: Have you heard about the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)?

Comment: yes but its a while ago. Thanks for the reminder Oded.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a question "why we need to split interface into 2 separate class and 2 concrete class". However, if it makes you understand the business logic, you can do that.

From a software metric perspective, the more cohesion you have, the stronger class design you get. There are a number of papers proven the hypothesis. You could have some references to this link [Introduce contents of cohesion metric](http://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-oo-cohesion.html)

In your case, I think you should split it up into two interfaces to deal with template test and test plan.

Comment: @Where would you put the mutual GetChildrenUnits method? In each interface and implement the code 2 times? NO...

Answer (score 0):

You should create an interface for each problem you have to face, and a class for each solution you create for on of such problems. I'd implement the class implementing IUnitDataProvider as a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), solving the problem internally with a lot more interfaces and classes. But for a facade your interface seems right. The only problem I see is that if TestPlan (and GetTestplanRootUnits) reefers to your test cases, I don't think it's a good idea to put it like that in a "Domain" Interface . It's okay to put things you need for test cases in an interface or class of the problem domain, as long as the thing you need actually exists and has sense in the problem domain by itself, after forgetting you need it for the tests. If you can't find it in the problem domain, and can't find a name for it that doesn't include Test something, then you should probably think in which problem domain that thing exists, and create an other interface & class for the things you are solving of that domain.

Comment: a facade bundles the complexity/details of several methods into one method. What has this pattern to do with my problem?

Comment: From what I can gather, I think your problem is too big to be completely solved by a single class. You seem to have a kind of CRUD of units, which support for some kind of tree in them. I think that's far too much for a single class to handle.

Comment: The same question to you too: Where would you put the mutual GetChildrenUnits method? In each interface and implement the code 2 times? NO...

Comment: Could you explain the whole context of what you are doing? What "Real life problem" are you solving?

Comment: puuh... that needs time. Do you need a real life description for a technical problem? You could have said create a UnitBaseDataProvider class for mutual implementations.

Comment: Yes. I don't think it's a technical problem. Design is about making the things easier for the programmers, not for the PC. It has a lot to do with the problem, and how humans perceive it, understand it, etc... It's way to make you work less, and produce more (More info here: http://talkingaboutsoftwaredesign.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/why-software-design/ ).

Comment: As I got no concrete Help just lots of philosophy advises I go for the 2 interfaces and a base class for the UnitDataProvider class having an Interface for mutual methods.